# Do even semiprimes $n$ always have an odd number of prime pairs $(x,y)$ where $x+y=n$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Even semiprimes $n=2p, p \in \mathbb{P}$.

**Examples**

$p=13$ has 5 prime pairs: (3,23)(7,19)(13,13)(19,7)(23,3)
$p=17$ has 7 prime pairs: (3,31)(5,29)(11,23)(17,17)(23,11)(29,5)(31,3)
$p=19$ has 3 prime pairs: (7,31)(19,19)(31,7)

Is it possible to show even semiprimes $n$ always have an odd number of prime pairs $(x,y)$ where $x+y=n$?

Comment: How far have you checked?

Comment: $10=3+7=5+5\,$.

Comment: Hint: Commutative property of addition

Comment: $n=10$ has $3$ pairs of primes: $(3,7)(5,5)(7,3)$ I've ran 100,000 iterations.

Comment: Oh, but then your claim is obvious.  The good pairs are matched except for $(p,p)$.

Comment: D'oh! I really should stew a little more before posting this stuff. Thanks! :)